# Changing the Visual Studio Default Class Setup

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, code-generation

I want to change the default code generated by visual studios 'add->class...' for C and C++.

Currently it looks like

```
#pragma once
class GlWindow
{
public:
    GlWindow(void);
    ~GlWindow(void);
};
```

Whereas I would like to use proper include guards, no premade constructor/destructor, and have the curly brace up next to the class name.

I've been annoyed by this ever since I've adapted my own coding style. I've been using my own script for it thus far, but having it add my class files to the project while visual studio is open would be a huge time saver.

Thanks a lot friends. Hopefully this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the code behind generating a generic C++ class in
INSTALLED_FOLDER\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\Generic\Class\Scripts\1033\default.js.Where INSTALLED_FOLDER represents "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\" 
You can write a custom template or wizard to generate code which meets your own standards. Hope this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730846%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will take you to the details to create a custom VS template.